# how to print HyExpression in python?

Tags: hy

how to print a object HyExpression as

```
HyExpression([
    HyExpression([
      HySymbol('/'),
      HyInteger(2)]),
    HyExpression([
      HyString('ceil')])])
```

as

> '((/ 2) ("ceil"))'

in console ?

Comment: ah!  I find the hy_repr http://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/contrib/hy_repr.html

Answer (score 4):

ah!  I have found the answer and its as follows [hy_repr](http://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/contrib/hy_repr.html)!

just use in .py

```
from hy.contrib.hy_repr import hy_repr

input_rule_list = '["?" ((/ 2) ("ceil"))]'
expr_input_list = hy.read_str(input_rule_list) #HyExpression 

#do something with this expr

print(hy_repr(expr_rule_parsed))

(cond [((get predicators "?") ) [((/ 2)) (("ceil"))]])
```

Cool!